# Updating JSON stored in a file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, serialization, json.net

I have some JSON stored in a file, as shown below.  What I want to do is to find `Task2`, change its state from `complete` to `deleted` and then save it back to the text file I got it from. But for the life of me, I cannot figure this one out.

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "task"     : "Task1",
            "quantity" : "(1)",
            "state"    : "incomplete",
            "changed"  : "never"    
        },
        {
            "task"     : "Task2",
            "quantity" : "(1)",                             
            "state"    : "complete",
            "changed"  : "never"                    
        },
        {
            "task"     : "Task3",
            "quantity" : "(1)",             
            "state"    : "deleted",
            "changed"  : "never"                    
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the code I have so far (using Json.Net)

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
    string txt = reader.ReadToEnd();

    JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(txt);
    JArray tasks = (JArray) jObject["tasks"];

    ....

    reader.Close();
}
```

What code do I need in order to update the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Json.Net (http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/89222)
and add its reference to your project and then you can do something like this...

```
 [DataContract]
        public class TaskClass
        {
            [DataMember(Name="task")]
            public string task { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Name="quantity")]
            public string quantity { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Name="state")]
            public string state { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Name = "changed")]
            public string changed { get; set; }
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class Tasks
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "tasks")]
            public IEnumerable<TaskClass> tasks { get; set; }
        }

//and you can deserialize json :

    string json = "{\"tasks\":[{\"task\": \"Task1\",\"quantity\": \"(1)\",\"state\": \"incomplete\",\"changed\": \"never\"},{\"task\": \"Task2\",\"quantity\": \"(1)\",\"state\": \"complete\",\"changed\": \"never\"},{\"task\":\"Task3\",\"quantity\": \"(1)\",\"state\": \"deleted\",\"changed\": \"never\" }]}";

            Tasks allTasks = new Tasks();
            allTasks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tasks>(json);

            foreach (TaskClass task in allTasks.tasks)
            {
                if (task.task.ToLower() == "task2")
                {
                    task.state = "deleted";
                }
            }

//and serialize it again as :

string value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objTasks);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want quite easily like this:

```
// Read the JSON file 
string json = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

// Parse the JSON
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
JArray tasks = (JArray)jObject["tasks"];

// Find the first JObject in tasks having a "task" property with a value of "Task2"
// If such an object exists, set its "state" property to "deleted"
JObject task2 = (JObject)tasks.FirstOrDefault(a => a["task"].ToString() == "Task2");
if (task2 != null)
{
    task2["state"] = "deleted";
}

// Write the JSON back to the file
File.WriteAllText(fileName, jObject.ToString());
```

Note that you will need to include `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code to be able to access the `FirstOrDefault()` method.